# Wiener measure in the space of functions of two or more variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Wiener measure in the space of continuous functions of two variables had been introduced by J. Yeh in the 1960 paper "*Wiener Measure in a Space of Functions of Two Variables*" [(AMS free access)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-03/S0002-9947-1960-0125433-1/S0002-9947-1960-0125433-1.pdf) 
(p. 435, eq. 2.2).

The measure is defined on the space $\mathcal{C}$ of continuous functions   $u: [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the following property: $u(t,0)=0$ and $u(0,s)=0$ for all $t,s\in [0, 1]$.

I would like to know whether we can use the same formula for the space of functions which do not start at 0.  More specifically, I mean the following question:

Suppose $\mathcal{C}'$ is the space of continuous functions   $u: [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the following property: $u(t,0)=u_0(t,0)$ and $u(0,s)=u_0(0,s)$ for all $t,s\in [0, 1]$, where $u_0 :[0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Can we use the same formula as in Eq. (2.2) of the above mentioned paper to define Wiener measure on $\mathcal{C}'$ , except that 
the initial conditions are  $u(t,0)=u_0(t,0)$ and $u(0,s)=u_0(0,s)$ for all $t,s\in [0, 1]$ ?

Comment: It's always interesting that JSTOR provides an expensive paywall access of the AMS journals, which are freely accessible on the AMS sites. I changed the link accordingly.

Comment: Yves, thank you very much for changing the link!

Comment: If I understood correctly: yest. Of course, in this case $u_{0,j}$ and $u_{i,0}$ are no longer equal to zero. By the way, "Brownian sheet" seems to be the now-standard term for this kind of constructions.

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwasnicki : Thank you very much for your answer!